# How to validate structure of json using phpleague/json-guard

Tags: json, validation, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 for an api and have an endpoint that accepts JSON along the lines of:

```
{
    "input": {
        "owner": "name of owner",
        "content": [
        ] 
    }
}
```

I want to get only the JSON inside `input` and ensure that it is valid, both structurally and based on the content.

Using http://json-guard.thephpleague.com and their basic example from the [overview](http://json-guard.thephpleague.com/validation/overview) page, everything comes back as valid no matter what I change as the input so I assume I am using it wrong.

From their example I have constructed the following. It passes validation. The issue is that I cannot get it to fail.

**routes file**

```
Route::post('validate', 'TestController@validateJson');
```

**TestController@validateJson**

```
public function validateJson()
{
    $dereferencer  = \League\JsonReference\Dereferencer::draft4();
    $schema        = json_decode('{ "properties": { "id": { "type": "string", "format": "uri" } } }');
    $data          = json_decode('{ "id": "https://json-guard.dev/schema#" }');

    $validator     = new \League\JsonGuard\Validator($data, $schema);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response($validator->errors());
    }

    return response('all ok');
}
```

I believe I might need to use the JSON Reference and define a custom schema, but until I can fully understand the example and get it to fail, I don't want to do anything more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

> everything comes back as valid no matter what I change as the input so I assume I am using it wrong.

It is hard to say exactly what the issue is without seeing an example of what input you tried.  Since the example schema validates that `id` is a `string` with the `uri` format, it should fail when you provide a string that is not a valid URI.  The following example will return a format error:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$schema        = json_decode('{ "properties": { "id": { "type": "string", "format": "uri" } } }');
$data          = json_decode('{ "id": "hello world" }');
$validator     = new \League\JsonGuard\Validator($data, $schema);

echo json_encode($validator->errors(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

There are some parts of JSON Schema that are unintuitive and you might not expect to pass.

A constraint only validates if it applies to that type.  If you don't pass an object validation will pass because the `properties` constraint only applies to objects:

```
$data = null;
var_dump((new \League\JsonGuard\Validator($data, $schema))->passes()); // true
```

To make non object inputs fail you need to specify `"type": "object"`.  Note that this will also happen with invalid JSON, since `json_decode` will return `null` when it fails.

Validation will also pass with an empty object:

```
$data = json_decode('{}');
var_dump((new \League\JsonGuard\Validator($data, $schema))->passes()); // true
```

To make the properties required you have to use the [required](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required-properties) keyword.

> I want to get only the JSON inside input and ensure that it is valid, both structurally and based on the content.

This schema should work as a starting point:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "input": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "owner": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1"
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "array"
                }
            },
            "required": ["owner", "content"],
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    "required": ["input"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

We are requiring that the input is an object, that it has an input property and no other properties, and that input is an object with the properties owner and content.  The minLength rule on owner is to prevent an empty string from passing.

> I believe I might need to use the JSON Reference and define a custom schema

You can write pretty complex schemas without using JSON Reference at all.  It's just a way to reuse a schema without copy and pasting.  For example, you might define a 'money' schema and use that for any dollar amounts in your API.

You definitely *will* need to write a custom schema.  The schema replaces the Laravel validation rules you would write for each endpoint otherwise.